# how to get data from following response in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

from the following api response i want to get data and i don't want to map it into html just get the data only.

please see the below image

[image: response]

I have tried doing

```
console.log(socket_data.data.socketId.status);
```

socket_data is array containing all response. It would be very helpful if you can provide solution.

Comment: As per your screenshot, `socket_data` is an object and not an array. Also, `socketId` property is an array. So you should get the result by this. `socket_data.data.socketId[0].status`

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan `socket_data` is an array not an object

Comment: oops, my bad. yes, its an array

Comment: can you tell us what you get by logging: socket_data then socket_data[0] ?

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA undefined

Comment: for both (socket_data & socket_data[0])?! if so, so from where you got your data showing in the screen shoot picture ?!!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the response that you get, `socket_data` and `socketId` are arrays not objects. So you should use its `index` to get the value

```
socket_data[0].data.socketId[0].status
```

Comment: saying data of undefined?

Comment: Then your `socket_data` would be an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `res.json()` and console.log the data

```js
const response = res.json()

//console.log the data
cosole.log(response.data)
```